Modeling nested lists in C
Problem
I am implementing a basic shell in C and am confused on how to best represent a list of commands where each command might be multiple commands that are run in parallel. For example, parsing the below batch file:
ls -l directory
cat README.md & du -sh directory
exit

would produce a data structure like such:
[
  [
    ["ls", "-l", "directory"],
  ],
  [
    ["cat", "README.md"],
    ["du", "-sh", "directory"],
  ],
  [
    ["exit"],
  ],
]

In particular, I am struggling to determine the most convenient data structure(s) to use as arguments to my exec_many function.
int exec_many(/* list of list of list of strings /*) {
    ...
}

I am willing to implement a subset of vector if that is necessary, but I assume there is a more C-like way to go about this problem.
What I've Tried
The only solution I've been able to come up with that meets the requirements is an API like such:
struct Command {
    string *args;
    int argc;
};

struct Commands {
    Command *commands;
    int count;
};

int exec_many(Commands *commands, int count) {
    ...
}

My issues with this solution are:

Defining a struct for each nested layer seems tedious and unnecessary
Constructing the structures requires full knowledge of length beforehand


Just execute the commands in a loop? If there's only one command, the loop iterates once and executes the single command. If there are multiple commands that should be run in the background the loop iterates many times. After the last command (doesn't matter if it's one or more) then wait for that last command to exit, unless it's also running in the background.

I agree with @Someprogrammerdude.  If you ignore the nested brackets, it's just a flat list of commands.

The control flow/execution of the program is not my issue. I am hoping to create a data structure where the looping requirements are encoded in the data structure itself. I want to separate the parsing of the commands and the execution since we need to detect batch file errors before executing any commands.

“tedious” basically describes any non-trivial C program, yes. That said, wrap the tedious logic into functions to simplify the code.

The structure you have come up with looks fine.

Defining a struct for each nested layer seems tedious and unnecessary

Einstein is often quoted as having said: Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler1. The complexity of a solution to a problem generally has to match the complexity of the problem it solves.
The problem you are trying to model involves a tree of entities; therefore, the solution must involve representing a tree of entities.
As a matter of fact, if the solution did not involve a tree, then I would frown.

Constructing the structures requires full knowledge of length beforehand

I would suggest that it is fine that it requires full knowledge of length beforehand, but if you really do not want that, then things will get significantly more complicated: what you actually need is a tree which consists of linked lists.
With a linked list, you can keep adding nodes until you have no more nodes to add. When processing the list, you keep processing nodes until there are no more nodes.

1 Einstein did not say exactly that; he said a more convoluted thing, which can be summarized, and generalized, by paraphrasing it like that. The summarized phrase has come to be known as Einstein's Razor. See Wikiquote: Albert Einstein, see Wikipedia: Philosophical razor, and see Quote investigator: Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler
